# Maven pom cannot solve jboss dependency

Tags: maven, jboss, pom.xml

I actually have a very simple POM, and still I get this Error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MyEE: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.roi:MyEE:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:jar:3.0.3.Final in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

This are my Dependencies

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3.Final</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

What is the reasone for this? Is this dependency depends on other jar?

Answer (score 1):

Look at its pom.xml file

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/jboss-javaee-6.0/3.0.3.Final/jboss-javaee-6.0-3.0.3.Final.pom

the packaging is pom, so you need to add a type "pom" in the dependency node

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I always got `Missing artifact org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:jar:3.0.3.Final` from Maven. Adding `<type>pom</type>` fixed my problem and saved my life. Thanks.